# Multiple Bak files restore for migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore

We have this old server we need to migrate to new server.

We have a script that will backup all the databases to folder `C:\SQLBackup`.

I've already migrated several newer servers with no issue

```
DECLARE @datapath VARCHAR(512)
Set @Datapath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14\MSSQL\DATA\'

SELECT 'use master; ' + 'Restore Database ' + '[' + DBName + ']' + ' From Disk =' + ''''+ 'C:SQLBackup\' + DBName + '.bak' +'''' + ' WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE N'+ DBName +'_DATA' + ' TO '' @datapath'' + DBname + '_DATA.mdf', MOVE N'+ DBName +'_LOG' TO @datapath' + DBName + '_LOG.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' ';'
FROM
    (SELECT db.name AS DBName
     FROM sys.databases db
     WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')) D
```

Thanks

I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near 'D'

Comment: here: `+ DBName +'_LOG' TO @datapath' + `

Comment: Dynamic sql can be hard on the eyes. The easiest the to do is step through piece by commenting out the rest of the line and find where your problem(s) are. Looks like you've got a few problems with how you are handling the variable and string escape sequences. For example, this runs fine (I HAVE NOT TESTED to make sure it actually generates valid statements) Just showing the concatenation syntax.

Comment: You don't even need dynamic SQL you can parameterize the `RESTORE` statement see https://dbfiddle.uk/CCM44TZu

Comment: Did you intent to prefix the _DATA and _LOG names with the literal `N` - `...MOVE NMyDb_LOG TO ...` instead of `...MOVE MyDb_LOG TO ...`?

Comment: Please add the full code with the line numbers and also post your question is the most relevant https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't consider this an answer, this is not tested to make sure it's generating anything valid. Its only meant to show what's wrong with your concatenation syntax.

```
DECLARE @Datapath VARCHAR(512);
SET @Datapath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14\MSSQL\DATA\';
SELECT 'use master; ' + 'Restore Database ' + '[' + DBName + ']' + ' From Disk =' + ''''+ 'C:SQLBackup\' + DBName + '.bak' +'''' + ' WITH  FILE = 1, MOVE N'+ DBName +'_DATA' + ' TO ' + @Datapath + DBname + '_DATA.mdf, MOVE N'+ DBName +'_LOG TO ' + @datapath + DBName + '_LOG.ldf,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5;'
FROM (
    SELECT
        db.name AS DBName
    FROM sys.databases db
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
) D
```

Comment: I did not realize stack overflow did that. that will help better in the future for questions.
thanks for the information .  I went into cyber security so MY SQL a little rusty